# Passing Arguments in Unix command line when using | symble

Tags: shell, unix, parameters, command, ls

I am trying to move all my video files that are in my pictures directory to my movies Directory. This is on a Mac by the way.

I thought I could simple Recurse through all my picture directories with an "ls -R"

Then I pipe that to grep -i ".avi" This give me all the movie files.

Now I pipe these values to "mv -n $1 ~/Movies" this I am hoping would move the files to the Movies folder.

I have a few Problems. 
 1. The "ls -R" does not list the path when listing the files. So I think I may fail to move the file. 
 2. I can not seem to get the file name to assign to the $1 in the mv command.

All together my command looks like this: Note I am running this from ~/Pictures

```
ls -R | grep -i ".avi" | mv -n $1 ~/Movies
```

So right now I am not sure which part is failing but I do get this error:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
   mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

If I remove the 'mv' command I get a listing of avi files with out the path. Example Below:

```
4883.AVI
4884.AVI
4885.AVI
4886.AVI
4887.AVI
...
```

Any one have any ideas on how I can get the path in the 'ls' or how to pass a value in between the '|' commands.

Thanks.

Comment: you are getting this error  because here $1 has value NULL, so to command `mv` its like you passed only one value. Thus its saying you need to pass source and destination both.

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you use the `find` command:

```
$ find -name "*.avi" -exec mv {} ~/Movies \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The bash `for` loop can help you find all the `avi` files easily

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.avi
do
   mv "$file" "$file"  ~/Movies/"$file"
done
```

Comment: This is not recursive, but you can use `shopt -s globstar; for file in **/*.avi` in `bash 4` or later.

Answer (score 0):

you should create simple copy.sh like this

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $1 ~/Movies/
```

An run command ./copy.sh "$(ls | grep avi)"

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this in many ways, one of it in my openion:

```
ls -R | grep -i ".avi" | while read movie
do
  echo " moving $movie"
  mv $movie ~/Movies/
done
```

Comment: Thank you I will run through this one. I believe you all have given me what I need. Thanks again!!

Comment: don't forget to accept answer which helped you the most. happy learning.

Comment: @chepner : will you plz explain the reason.

Answer (score -1):

Use backticks

```
mv `ls *.avi` ~/Movies
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this.